# Hot to disable 3 finger tap (Libinput)

Tags: touchpad, plasma, libinput, multi-touch

I want to disable the paste action associated with the 3 finger tapping because it is not a behavior helpful for me and also somehow dangerous.

Most of the post (for ex. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881939/libinput-how-to-map-different-tappings-to-buttons-tappingbuttonmap-has-no-effe)) report either to:

- add `TappingButtonMap` to xorg.conf ( this option allows only to invert button not to disable them).
- set `ButtonMapping property by CLI  ->`xinput set-prop $ID ButtonMapping 1 2 3 ...`  ( this actually changes the physical button )

Both solutions are not sufficient for my purpose.

- I think it is not possible with libinput to disable one single tapping, am I right?
- Is there any Plasma setting that can help to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also searched a lot how to disable the 3 finger tap, because I was using libinput-gestures and it fired the tap when I wanted to swipe. But I think that libinput doesn't provides for now a configuration to disable one of the TappingButton.

If you really want to disable the 3 finger tap, you can download your version of libinput from the gitlab https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput (be sure to download the same version as yours by downloading it from the release list https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/).

Then, you will have to modify the line 128 of the  evdev-mt-touchpad-tap.c file. Replace

```
if (nfingers > 3)
```

By

```
if (nfingers > 2)
```

You can now compile and install libinput following the instructions given on https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html

Be sure to download all the dependencies that meson needs.

In my case (Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome 3.28.3), I had to install

- libudev-dev
- libmtdev-dev
- libevdev-dev
- libwacom-dev
- check
- valgrind

Answer (score 2):

Open tweak-tool and turn off `Middle-click paste`

For vscode

1. go to settings (`ctrl` + `,`).
2. search for `selectionClipboard`
3. disable Editor: Selection Clipboard

You can simply set "editor.selectionClipboard": false in your user settings

Comment: interestingly, this works for me. So there are two clipboards out there? (I'm on 19.10 with Wayland)